# How can I access a HTML element that is written in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make like button, where you can like an object and it turns red. The problem is that I can't access the HTML element because it isn't implemented in HTML but in javascript. Is there a way to access such a class?

These are the selectors which should take the HTML element
`

```
const likeBtn = document.querySelector(".like_btn");
const likeIcon = document.querySelector("#icon");
```

`

This is the event listener

```
let clicked = false;

console.log(likeBtn)
 likeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if(!clicked) {
          clicked = true;
          likeIcon.innerHTML = `<i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>`
     } else {
         clicked = false;
        likeIcon.innerHTML = `<i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>`
    }
 })
```

This is the part where I implement the HTML elements in javascript
`

```
const displayItems = (items) => {
    const htmlString = Array.from(items).map((item) => {
            return `
            <li class="item">
            <button class="like_btn">
            <span id="icon"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i></span>
            </button>
                <h2>${item.name}</h2>
                <p>Type: ${item.type}</p>
                <img src="${item.image}"></img>
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    itemList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};
```

`

I tried to put the event listener into the "displayItems" function but it still doesn't work

Comment: When you change the value of the innerHTML property of any HTMLElement in the DOM, the elements found in such value get created and they are alive in the DOM. So they are available to the querySelector function also. Anyway a problem I see in your code is creating new items having the same id and that’s not valid. The id should be unique in the DOM

Comment: After you create the element you get or attach its reference to another variable and then do the manipulation you want